# Bootstrap responsive Carousel, with custom height doesnt resize on Mobile, Tablets

Tags: html, css, image, carousel, slideshow

I have a responsive image slider which I currently have with a width which takes up the entire screen (100%), and a height of 600px due to the images being of various sizes.

When i resize my browser, and or navigate to the site in question on a mobile device, due to the custom 600px height size applied, the image does not correctly resize to fit the screen.

If I remove the height and or comment out the height within my css page, I no longer have the issue on mobile devices and the image resizes accordingly. However within a desktop browser I then face the issue wherein I have images with various height, and cannot overcome this with simply applying a class with css properties, and or a style element within my img tag as this does not work. Please see my example code below.

HTML:

```
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
</ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
            <img class='img-responsive fill' src="img/example.jpg" >
    </div>
    <div class="item">
            <img class='img-responsive fill' src="img/example2.jpg">
    </div>           
</div>

<!-- Controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next"></span>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
header.carousel .fill {
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the easiest way would be using bootstrap media queries to set different height for different screen resolutions http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries
but I'd better use some aspect ratio tweaks here http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html

Comment: Hi @godblessstrawberry your answer gave me an indication and pointed me in the right direction, thank you for your prompt response.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<style>
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1224px) {
  #img1{
          height:600px !important;
       }
         #img2{
          height:600px !important;
       }
       </style>

       <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
</ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
            <img class='img-responsive fill' id= "img1" src="img/example.jpg" >
    </div>
    <div class="item">
            <img class='img-responsive fill' id= "img2" src="img/example2.jpg">
    </div>           
</div>

<!-- Controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: Hi @Anto Sujesh thank you for your response, your answer helped me with my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following Solved my issue:

I created css @media elements as such:

```
@media (min-width: 200px) {
  div.test > img{ height: 300px !important ;}
}

@media (min-width: 300px) {
  div.test > img{ height: 300px !important; }
}

@media (min-width: 400px) {
  div.test > img{ height: 300px !important; }
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  div.test > img{ height: 400px !important ;}
}
@media, (min-width: 800px) {
  div.test > img{ height: 600px !important ; }
}
```

I then wrapped my html img tag with a div class of test and this resized my image accordingly with the css properties:

```
<!-- Indicators -->
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
</ol>

<!-- Wrapper for slides -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
            <div class="test"><img class='img-responsive fill' src="img/example.jpg" ></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
            <div class="test"<img class='img-responsive fill' src="img/example2.jpg"></div>
    </div>           
</div>

<!-- Controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next"></span>
</a>
```

One thing to note the css properties did not work without the:

```
!important
```

I assume this is due to boostrap.css and or bootstrap.min.css predefined properties which were taking priorty.